# What is the definition of mountainous area?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, flight-planning

MEA, MORA, grid MORA, and MOCA for a non-mountainous area gives 1,000 ft clearance from the highest obstacle, and in mountainous area gives 2,000 ft clearance from the highest obstacle.

But what is the exact definition of a mountainous area?

I have also heard that MOCAs have a different clearance calculation for the mountainous area depending on the terrain/obstacle elevation, (3000 ft - 5000 ft gets 1500 ft clearance) and (above 5000 ft gets 2000 ft clearance) can someone clarify this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're asking about the USA.)

[14 CFR 91.177(a)(2)(i)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=3efaad1b0a259d4e48f1150a34d1aa77&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.10&idno=14#se14.2.91_1177) says (emphasis mine):

> In the case of operations over an area **designated as a mountainous
>   area in part 95 of this chapter**, an altitude of 2,000 feet above the
>   highest obstacle within a horizontal distance of 4 nautical miles from
>   the course to be flown; or [...]

If you then go to [14 CFR 95](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=be37fe6717bd9dd7cb4a77aaf441c06c&mc=true&node=pt14.2.95&rgn=div5#sp14.2.95.b), you'll see that it defines mountainous areas by latitude and longitude. It's entirely useless for practical purposes, but at least it's precise :-)

As for the MOCA, I can't find anything to support the different definitions that you mentioned. 95.1(e) simply says:

> (e) The MOCA assures obstruction clearance on an ATS route, ATS route
>   segment, or other direct route, and adequate reception of VOR
>   navigation signals within 22 nautical miles of a VOR station used to
>   define the route.

The AIM and PC/G support that; there's no other definition that I could find.

Comment: Thanks alot for that :D

Answer (score 1):

Designated mountainous areas include those areas having a terrain **elevation differential** exceeding 3,000 feet within 10 nautical miles within those one arc-second quadrangles overlying terrain or U.S. territorial waters. This new definition would also align with that used by ICAO.

Comment: Do you have any sources you can add to back up your answer?