# Why does V165 have two different MEAs over the same route section?

Tags: air-traffic-control, aeronautical-charts, altitude

[image]

Why does V165 have two distinct MEAs which vary by a large factor (apart from the 180$^{\circ}$ rule of altitudes) considering they would be clearing the same obstacles and receiving signals from the same NAV aids?

Comment: Please refer IFR  chart containing V165

Comment: If you are jetting along in a certain direction, there might be a big mountain ahead of you. but if  you are tooling along in the opposite direction the mountain will be behind you.  This difference is called out to you so you will be safely boring holes in air instead of granite.

Comment: If the obstacle is at the midpoint of the route wouldn't the aircraft have to clear it by the same altitude

Comment: @DarshanPatil - Welcome to Aviation! I've added a chart snippet to your question and changed the question slightly to refer to it.  If that's not what you intended, please feel free to edit.

Comment: That's great I appreciate it , I was unable to upload the picture myself . Thank you @ Steve V

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason is terrain. Here's what the VFR sectional looks like:

[image]

You can see that the terrain rises sharply to over 3000' close to WINLO intersection, which is too high to provide IFR obstacle clearance (1000', or 2000' over [mountainous areas](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/59383/62)) at an MEA of 4000'. An aircraft flying south on V165 would need to be well above the terrain before reaching WINLO, whereas one flying north from WINLO can use a lower altitude.